# MVC 4 Export To CSV - Save As dialogue box not working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, http-headers, download

I am trying Export `csv` file to the User with Open/Save option.

My issue is some what similar to [how-to-force-chrome-to-open-an-open-file-dialog-when-downloading-a-file-via-as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933531/how-to-force-chrome-to-open-an-open-file-dialog-when-downloading-a-file-via-as)`(It is downloading the file in Chrome and Firefox)`, I have tried with the solution suggested by `@Dev` but it is not working.

I wrote my code as below:-

```
return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csvData),
                    "text/csv", filename);
```

But, it was not working in Chrome. The file is getting downloaded by default.

Then after googling , I found [returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc), from which I was trying to do something like below:-

```
var csvData = "hello";// I am filling this variable with ,y values from DB!
    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        // for example foo.bak
        FileName = "test",
        Inline = false,
    };
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", 
        cd.ToString());
    return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csvData),
        "text/csv");
```

but still it was downloading the file in Chrome. then I came across [how-to-display-open-save-dialog-asp-net-mvc-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139316/how-to-display-open-save-dialog-asp-net-mvc-4/14139388), where `@JoãoSimões` mentioned as:-

> That is browser dependent. If you set to download automatically to a
>   given folder, the browser will download automatically. Firefox and
>   Chrome are some browsers with this behavior. –  João Simões Jan 3 at
>   13:09

If the above is true, then how can I overcome my problem? How can I get the open/save dialogue ?
I am unable to Export my CSV with open/save option.

**Edit 1**

I was trying to do something like this (got it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382716/mvc-javascript-method-call-not-bringing-up-excel-save-dialog?rq=1)):-

```
public class ExcelResult : ActionResult
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Buffer = true;
            context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;     filename=" + FileName);
            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(Data));
        }
    }
```

and My controller code:-

```
return new ExcelResult
                {
                    FileName = "sample.xls",
                    Path = "",
                    Data = csvData
                };
```

but still, it is downloading the Excel ...

**Edit 2**

Tried opening the excel with `HttpContext.Current.Response`

```
/// <summary>
/// Export CSV 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public void DownloadCSV()
{
    try
    {
        var csvData = Session["CSVData"].ToString();


        byte[] getContent = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csvData);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", getContent.Length.ToString());
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "testing.csv");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(getContent);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage message = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent("Error Exporting Data")
        };

        throw new System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException(message);

    }

}
```

but, still not working!!!

Comment: Does the open/save dialogue appear when you download an csv/xls file form any other page like [this](http://www.andrewpatton.com/countrylist.csv) ? If not, it's probably not of your code but with the browser settings.

Comment: @developer10214:- The link you have posted, I am getting dialogue box.  I guess then either its my code issues or some alien attack!!!

I am still scratching head..

Comment: You code is perfectly fine. It depends on browser settings. There is no way to get around this and you cannot/shouldn't try to override user's browser settings as it would be like hacking the machine.

Comment: What do you mean by it is still downloading? Chrome, Safari & Firefox will download file straight to downloads folder. It will not ask for Save dialog unless user right click on the link & click Save Link as. Another option would be to use File API.

Comment: @AkashKava - True! I got that point. But there should have been something which would allow us to override that feature. Or in other words what @Poornima said, `I wanted to override browser settings.` and as per her Hack it!

Comment: @ShubhDasgupta I told you, it's HTML5 File API which allows you to ask user for Save As location from JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@shubh have you tried [How to force Chrome to open an "open file dialog" when downloading a file vía ASP.NET codebehind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933531/how-to-force-chrome-to-open-an-open-file-dialog-when-downloading-a-file-via-as) second solution they have put image in where they show how to open dialog box in chrome. I have chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m in that if you go to setting in that advance setting then down you will find check box which was given in above link answer, that will solve your problem I think.
If still not working then might be problem with your browser just update it to latest version then try again.
**Edit 1:** 
If you put your file name extension .xls then it will open in excel for csv you need to put file name as `FileName = "sample.csv",` then it will open in csv format.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewtoCSVExport.csv");
Response.Charset = string.Empty;
Response.ContentType = "application/text";
```

for more check this http://surajdeshpande.wordpress.com/2013/09/03/export-gridview-data-to-csv-file-in-asp-net/

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. I tried it 2 days back when `@developer10214` suggested that it may be browser issue!!  But, it was not working. I have even uninstalled chrome and installed it back... :(

Comment: I uninstalled and installed my chrome, to have the latest version as it was not updating. But didn't work out. I just tried with hard-coding file name, but no result. Lets see, I have contacted my network team, if they have done something fishy. grrrr... Thanks for your suggestions satish! Really appreciate.

Comment: Try to add this code and check it might be working 
`Response.Output.Write(getContent.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();`

Comment: It may be late. But after a lot of effort I was not able to get it. Thanks to my superiors who understood the problem. Your link was helpful to make the understand [**how-to-force-chrome-to-open-an-open-file-dialog**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933531/how-to-force-chrome-to-open-an-open-file-dialog-when-downloading-a-file-via-as). Thanks for your efforts +1. Will request you to update your answer highlighting the link :)

Answer (score 1):

If the user has configured his browser to automatically download files, there's absolutely nothing you could do on the server to force this dialog to appear. I am afraid that what you are trying to achieve is impossible.

Comment: You may be right! After scratching my head for more than 9 days, I also feel the same. Let me see, if I can find any alternative solution for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to [supply another value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016842/open-save-dialog-in-chrome-browser) for your content-disposition header:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
```

Comment: It is still downloading the file :(